# Accessing the element in an array

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm performing an array return:

```
CStringArray & CQueue:: GetUsed()
{
   return  m_Used;
}
```

Instead of storing this return value in an array and accessing each element:

```
CStringArray lastUsed;
lastUsed.Append(m_Queue.GetUsed());
CString a = lastUsed.ElementAt(1);
```

is there a way in which I can directly access the element at a location something like this?

```
CString a = (m_Queue.GetUsed()).ElementAt(2);
```

Comment: Did you actually try to run the code from your question's last line?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetAt` function

```
CString CStringArray::GetAt( int <nIndex> ) const;
```

e.g.:

```
CStringArray arr;
arr.Add(L"test");
arr.Add(L"ing");
cout << arr.getAt(0) << arr.getAt(1) << endl;
```

output:

```
testing
```